# How to handle API requests with Record Limits using R

Tags: r, api, get, httr

I do not have any code to share, but am looking for advice on the best way to handle API record limits. I am pulling data for a restful api service and the record limit is 1000 records. The data goes back about three years. I am using HTTR package in R to use a GET request with multiple parameters.

I want to be able to pull as much data into memory that R can handle which in my experience is around 2 million records. Loops do not seem ideal. I managed to create a list of date ranges (about 30 day range) which when created into a dataframe leaves me with about 40 dataframes where about half are still reaching a record limit of 1000 rows. The date ranges do not overlap. The only thing I can think of is to make the query small enough so that the data pulled back is not reaching or exceeding the record limit and to then do a rbind on all the data.

Is there any workarounds for querying restful api's that have these record limits. If not, then my approach may be to query small enough date ranges and loop the GET request until it has queried all date ranges in my list and cache the files. Then perhaps query from the cached files. Is there a better approach?

Comment: Can you please clarify ... is this question about working with a rate-limiting API, or about dealing with large amounts of data in R-resident memory? Are you caching your query returns? Is the data volatile/updated enough so that normal caching mechanisms don't work?

Comment: The data is static in the format of json (96 unique features (most of which have NAs). So I am able to query the data and use jsonlite to pull hte attributes into a dataframe. Some of those dataframes reach a 1000 rows but some come back with fewer rows. New data gets added a few times a week, but older records have some input mistakes so I see they don't get updated. For caching, I am planning just to write the data to csv, naming the files based on the date range I used to query. I have not hit any fetch_curl_memory errors. So that's why I believe the API has a record limit.

Comment: I don't see the relevance of a good portion of your question text: if you think you're being rate-limited, it doesn't matter (to me) if you will eventually pull millions of rows and cache them to file. The fact that you may run into memory limits is completely ancillary to pulling from the API. For those frames that return exactly 1000 (suggesting a cap), perhaps you can get the max date observed and run another query from that date until the query's original end date, then `rbind` and `!duplicated` it. That's all I can think of given the theoretical nature of this question.